# Don't start nested test cases when outer test case fails with JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I have the following test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class HierarchicalTest {

    @Test
    void checkOuter() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class PrepBTest {

        @Test
        void checkInnerA() {}

        @Test
        void checkInnerB() {}
    }
}
```

I want to have the behavior that `checkInnerA()` and `checkInnerB()` won't be executed when `checkOuter()` fails.

On the other side `checkInnerB()` should be executed when `checkInnerA()` fails because it is on the same level.

Is there a simple soulution (e.g. with JUnit 5 extension) to achieve this behavior?
In my opinion that's often the behavior which is wished.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

As of JUnit Jupiter 5.4, you can develop an extension that implements the `TestWatcher` and `ExecutionCondition` APIs to achieve this behavior.

In the `testFailed()` method from the `TestWatcher` API you need to track test classes that have failures, and you need to store this information in the *root* `ExtensionContext.Store`.

In the `evaluateExecutionCondition()` method from the `ExecutionCondition` API you need to determine if the current class is a `@Nested` test class (i.e., an *inner class*) and check if the enclosing test class had failures. If that holds true, you need to *disable* the current `@Nested` test class and otherwise *enable* it.

Those are the general guidelines. For a working example, please see the [SkipOnFailuresInEnclosingClassExtension](https://github.com/sbrannen/junit5-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/extensions/SkipOnFailuresInEnclosingClassExtension.java) I just posted to my `junit5-demo` repository on GitHub. That example goes one step further by only skipping `@Nested` test classes if they are also annotated with `@SkipOnFailuresInEnclosingClass`. The [OuterTests](https://github.com/sbrannen/junit5-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/working/OuterTests.java) class shows the annotation and extension in action.

---

No, as of JUnit Jupiter 5.3, there is currently no way to achieve that with out-of-the-box solutions.

You could potentially write a custom extension that tracks the success of tests in an enclosing test class -- for example, by implementing `TestExecutionExceptionHandler`. That would need to be stored in the `ExtensionContext.Store`. The extension would then need to implement `ExecutionCondition` to programmatically *disable* nested test classes.

It's unfortunately not very straightforward to track the "success" of previously executed tests currently, but that should improve with the introduction of the new `TestWatcher` extension API that is currently slated for inclusion in the upcoming JUnit Jupiter 5.4: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542

Comment: Any example now that [`TestWatcher`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html) has been added (experimentally)?

Comment: Yes, I just implemented an example "just for fun", and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice :) I'd upvote but I've already done so. Just a couple of questions: (1) When I looked at `TestWatcher` my first instinct was to use a `BeforeEachCallback` and _abort_ a test if a previous one failed (e.g. by using assumptions). Is it more idiomatic to _disable_ the test using an `ExecutionCondition`? (2) I've never been entirely clear on the `ExtensionContext` hierarchy, but do you need to use the _root_ context or would using the enclosing class' context be sufficient (if it's not too difficult to acquire)?

Comment: `ExecutionCondition` is more idiomatic for this: you want to the test be skipped entirely, including extensions for the method. In this example, I'm skipping the entire test class.

Comment: Yes, I do believe the use of the _root_ context is necessary here. I believe the parent context is gone once executing the nested test class.