# How to define priority in JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have some unit test built with Junit in a Java project.
The only issue is that I want to define the order/priority of the tests.
I mean... I'm using `@BeforeAll` to execute first test, which is the login process and to get the access for the postlogin functionalities.
But right after that, I want to run another specific test.

And then the rest...

I checked and there is an option to use `@Order()` annotation, but my idea is not to be ordering every test like this... I just wanna run first the login, and then a test that I need to run all the others. So after the first two test, the others doesn't matter in which order they are.

Comment: `I'm using @BeforeAll to execute first test` do you mean that one of your tests actually sets up "environment" for your other tests? I think that is is a bad idea, all of your tests should be independent.

Comment: So, I need to Login In order I get some tokens to access to all the other functionalities.. How do you suggest of doing that?

Comment: You should do it as a part of your `@Before` or `@BeforeAll` methods - it should not be about invoking a test which does it (sets up environment for you).

Comment: I don't get it... I should or shouldn't use @BeforeAll for login process? The second test that  I need is to get a dynamic value of a variable that I will need for other test.

Comment: If your tests need you to login first then that should happen in methods annotated with `@BeforeAll` or `@BeforeEach` (whichever makes more sense in your context). However, if you're trying to test the _actual login code_, then that needs to be in an actual test method (e.g. `@Test`) and not in a `@BeforeXXX` method.

Comment: Ok, agreed on that... But what happens with the second one? I also need to get a var (after log in) that I need to do it before the rest of the tests. So I need to define test 1: login, test 2: to get a var, all the other tests

Comment: I think you are confusing setup from the test. Logging in and obtaining some information should be part of the set up. You should not provide information necessary for a particular test by running another test. Any information that a tests need should be set up in the @Before method.

Comment: In addition, you should structure the tests such that all related tests are in the same class. This would mean that all tests that require you to login should be in the same class and that class should have a @Before method. If tests do not need to login, you should consider moving them to a separate class. Lastly, "login" functionality is something that seems external to the tests. You should separate out this logic and test logining in independently from the code that executes after the login has been performed. Do not build dependencies in your tests.

Answer (score 5):

First, having unit tests depend on other unit tests is typically bad design. The [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order) mentions this:

> Although true *unit tests* typically should not rely on the order in which they are executed, there are times when it is necessary to enforce a specific test method execution order — for example, when writing *integration tests* or *functional tests* where the sequence of the tests is important, especially in conjunction with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.

Consider if what you're doing is testing or set-up. If the action of logging in is just set-up for your tests then you should do this in a method annotated with `@BeforeAll` or `@BeforeEach`, whichever makes more sense in your context. Afterwards, you may need to clean-up using `@AfterAll` or `@AfterEach`, depending on which "before annotation" you used.

If you're actually trying to *test* the login code then try to separate these tests from the others. You could do this by moving them into a separate class file or even leveraging `@Nested` classes (if appropriate). Instead of having your later tests require a *real* login you should use a *fake* login. In other words, mock the dependencies needed for the later tests. This will remove the inter-test dependency situation. And don't be afraid to re-"login" for each test (e.g. by using `@BeforeEach`); if you're using mocks this shouldn't be too expensive.

*Note: As of JUnit 5.4 you might even be able to abort some tests if previous tests fail using a [`TestWatcher`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html) extension, as mentioned in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112537/dont-start-nested-test-cases-when-outer-test-case-fails-with-junit-5). However, using such an approach seems better suited for **integration tests** rather than **unit tests**.*

---

That said, what you want should be possible. You mention [`@Order`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Order.html) but then say you're hesitant to use it because you don't want to order every method, only make sure that two tests run before all the others. You don't have to add the annotation to every method. If you look at the documentation of [`MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.html), you'll see:

> `MethodOrderer` that sorts methods based on the [`@Order`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Order.html) annotation.
>
> Any methods that are assigned the same order value will be sorted arbitrarily adjacent to each other.
>
> Any methods not annotated with `@Order` will be assigned a default order value of [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true#MAX_VALUE) which will effectively cause them to appear at the end of the sorted list.

And from [`Order.value()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Order.html#value()):

> Elements are ordered based on priority where a lower value has greater priority than a higher value. For example, [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true#MAX_VALUE) has the lowest priority.

This means you only need to annotate your two tests with `@Order` and leave the rest alone. All the test methods without the `@Order` annotation will run in any order, but after the first two tests.

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class MyTests {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void firstTest() {}

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void secondTest() {}

    @Test
    void testFoo() {}

    @Test
    void testBar() {}

    // other tests...

}
```

Comment: Thanksss!! This is my first experience with Unit Test, so thanks for all the information